# Need advice with SELECT * FROM

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `lose` > '1' 
AND `win` > '1' 
ORDER BY win DESC 
LIMIT ".$lowerlimit.", 30
```

This is for Leaderboard on the Gaming site. Problem is this:

```
Players        Win       Lose
Player 1:      94         40
Player 2:      91         56
Player 3:      9          12
----------------------------
Player 12:     82         50
Player 13:     8          10
```

Player 12 must be on 3rd place. What did i do wrong?

Comment: Is `lose` a string or numeric column?  If numeric, it should be `WHERE \`lose\` > 1`

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a varchar column! That means your order by will be alphabetic rather than numeric

Comment: yep, should be numbers!

Comment: As others have said, don't store numbers as varchar.  However, you can `order by cast(win as signed)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, it's sorting alphabetically.  It doesn't matter that all your data just *happens* to be numbers.  You'll need to update your schema to store wins and losses as a numeric data type, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  players text,
  win int,
  lose int
);
```

Then change your query to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `lose` > 1
AND `win` > 1
ORDER BY win DESC 
LIMIT ".$lowerlimit.", 30
```

Also, I'd think on a leaderboard, you'd want to allow people who have *never* lost, correct?  You might want to remove `WHERE lose > 1`

Answer (score 0):

If lose and win are not a text/ntext column then you can try with below code

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE cast(lose as int) > 1
AND cast(win as int)> 1
ORDER BY cast(win as int) DESC
LIMIT ".$lowerlimit.", 30
```